# Updating a pointer value with an integer during a recursive call in postorder traversal of a BST

Tags: c++, debugging, pointers, binary-search-tree

```
int MovieTree::countMovieNodes()
{
    int count = 0;
    int* c = &count;
    countMovieNodes(root,c);
    return *c;
}
void MovieTree::countMovieNodes(MovieNode *node, int *c)
{
    int count;
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        count ++;
        countMovieNodes(node->leftChild, c);
        countMovieNodes(node->rightChild, c);
    }

}
```

My code is returning 0, so clearly I am misunderstanding the methodology to updating the pointer values. How do I fix this? I don't think my logic for post order traversal of the BST is the issue.

Comment: We'll need all the code for the program so we can compile it and run it ourselves.  When you don't know what's broken, be very careful about assuming what isn't broken.

Comment: The referenced code is everything that is being called in this instance. The other parts of the code are neither affecting nor interacting with this code outside of this code's functionality. The only pertinent thing aside from this would be the class function. I would upload the code, however, it spans two large files and a header file.

Comment: You need to post enough code to create an actual program to reproduce the problem  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `count ++;` triggers undefined behavior because it's reading from an uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your current format, creating a new count is still making of copy of it, just incerment the pointer directly:

```
int MovieTree::countMovieNodes()
{
    int count = 0;
    int* c = &count;
    countMovieNodes(root,c);
    return *c;
}
void MovieTree::countMovieNodes(MovieNode *node, int *c)
{
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        ++*c;
        countMovieNodes(node->leftChild, c);
        countMovieNodes(node->rightChild, c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't actually use the `c` parameter (it just passes it on to recursive calls, which also don't use `c`). Your code also creates a local `count` variable in each call, which is only incremented (not written to or read from).

What you should do instead is

1. delete `int count;`
2. change `count ++;` to `(*c)++;` (or `*c += 1;` if you don't like parens) to increment the `count` variable in the top-level `countMovieNodes()` call)